# The menu is not transitioning when closing

Tags: javascript, html, css

When clicking on the menu icon the menu opens in a good way with tranisiton.
but when I close the menu it is not closing with transition.
How can I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/mfxwsk7g/

I tryed to add this code but it doesn't work:

`.navigation__checkbox:not(checked)~.navigation__nav .navigation__list { opacity: 1; }`

Comment: Please do not just show snippets here that lack context - a proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question (and not just dumped onto an external platform.)

Comment: sure. I will keep it in the mind. thank you.

Comment: But can you help me with this question?

Comment: Don't know right now, and as long as you can't be bothered at least to do what was asked of you, I won't make an attempt to find out.

Comment: I edited the css. It is about the lines to line 31 in css. https://jsfiddle.net/2vk4r7je/ I can't delete the rest of the code because the menubar doesnt work.

Comment: What part about this belongs directly into your question, _instead of_ just being dumped onto an external platform like jsfiddle, is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
.navigation__checkbox {
    display: none;
}

/*menu icon*/
.navigation__button {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 300;
    cursor: pointer;

    top: 2em;
    right: 2em;
    height: 4.2em;
    width: 3em;
}

.navigation__nav {
    position: static;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 200;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    transition: opacity 1000ms;
}

.navigation__list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20em;
    left: 45em;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1000ms;
}

.navigation__checkbox:checked~.navigation__nav .navigation__list {
    opacity: 1;
}


.navigation__checkbox:not(checked)~.navigation__nav .navigation__list {
    opacity: 1;
}


.navigation__checkbox:checked~.navigation__nav {
    width: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}



.navigation__item {
    margin: 0em;
}

.navigation__link:link,
.navigation__link:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #333;
    font-family: avenir_next_lt_probold;
    font-size: 4.5em;
}


.navigation__link span {
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navigation__link:hover {
    color: #C1D0D0;
}


.navigation__icon {
    position: relative;
}


.navigation__icon,
.navigation__icon::before,
.navigation__icon::after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2.2rem;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 3em;
}


.navigation__icon::before,
.navigation__icon::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 400ms;
}

.navigation__icon::before {
    top: -.8em;
}

.navigation__icon::after {
    top: .8em;
}

.navigation__button:hover .navigation__icon::before {
    top: -1em;
}

.navigation__button:hover .navigation__icon::after {
    top: 1rem;
}


/*checkbox*/
.navigation__button {
    width: 3em;
    height: 2em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}


.navigation__checkbox:checked+.navigation__button .navigation__icon::before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.navigation__checkbox:checked+.navigation__button .navigation__icon {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navigation__checkbox:checked+.navigation__button .navigation__icon::after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
<input type="checkbox" class="navigation__checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
<label for="nav-toggle" class="navigation__button"><span 
class="navigation__icon" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-easing="linear" data-aos-duration="600" aria-label="toggle navigation menu">
</span>
</label>
<!--<div class="navigation__background"></div>-->
 <nav class="navigation__nav" role="navigation">
<div class="navigation__list">
<li ><a href="#" class="navigation__link" >Over ons</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Service</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Contact</a></li>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is still a problem. Because you changed the position:fixed to position:static. the menu is only opening in the top of the website. So when I scroll down and try to open the menu, the menu is opening on the top of the website instead of the place where I was while scrolling. How can we solve this?